# Include relevant site participation for privilege threshold instead of reputation alone

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, privileges, participation

Currently, the privilege is decided by a minimum reputation, say 2000 for edits.

Suppose Alice has been a long-time user and keeps the site clean and organized by making quality edits, and has a rep of 1500.

Shouldn't Alice get the edit privilege earlier, as she has more edits, better approved to suggested ratio than some other users with a lot of rejected edits? She doesn't have much to contribute but wants to improve the site.

**Proposal:**
Some weight should be given to appropriate actions so far in deciding the privilege grant. For example, 1750 rep + 100 edits with 80% approval rate will allow  you to bypass review queue.  Not the perfect or data-backed formula, but it can discussed.

Comment: I think your post might be better-received it if focused on just your first question.  The site format generally works best when you ask only one question per post.  You might also want to do some searching to check whether there are other questions asking about mitigations against incorrect/abusive edits; I suspect there's stuff on that here on Meta.

Comment: "I think your post might be better-received it if focused on just your first question. " That doesnt seem to be correct @D.W.. See linked question in the sidebar. thanks for the help anyway. Guess I should stay to where I hail from.

Comment: Edits already count towards this. Each successful one gives you +2 reputation so 100 edits would give you 200 reputation. If you've 1750 rep by other means that makes 1950 so we pretty much do what you're suggesting right now.

Comment: @RobertLongson I meant that the bar for edit privilege can be lowered(from 2000) if some edits are made. you went too far in the wrong direction with the maths. See it this way.. 1550 rep and then someone does 100 edits-> 1750 and voila! edit privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the benefit would be of adding this much complexity in giving out new privileges for users that already are on the right track. Specially for suggested edits that already comes with a reputation bonus of +2 for each approved edit (up to 1000 rep in total).

If I look at your proposed parameters on Stack Overflow [452](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1112592) users would gain the full edit privilege now. I'm not convinced those 452 users will be super thrilled to receive a privilege a bit sooner as they are obviously on the right track. You could argue it releases some stress on the suggested edits review queue but that queue is dominated by robo-reviewers so it hardly ever is a problem to all reviews handled in a timely manner.

That basically rules out the full-edit privilege to be a good candidate to include site-participation into the privilege threshold.

How about other privileges? Flags (500 rep), Close votes (3,000 rep) and maybe delete (10,000 rep)? There isn't a lack of number of users that can flag or vote, not even on Stack Overflow. There is a lack of participation in using those privileges. Bringing a small number of people to that pool isn't beneficial in the grand scheme of things.

The gamification as is works well enough as motivator to end-up with a certain privilege.  While it sometimes seem to take for ever, specially near the end, the reachability of a privilege is enough motiviation to keep people doing the right thing. They will be rewarded anyway.

Let's not implement this feature request.

Comment: Patience is the key it seems.